# Create Geolocation field type using java code

Tags: soap-api, custom-field, metadata-api, geolocation

I am using com.sforce.soap.metadata.FieldType and com.sforce.soap.metadata.CustomField classes to create custom fields using java code. Now I want to create a field which is type of geolocation in salesforce but there is no such constant FieldType.geolocation, So my question is that how can i create geolocation field using these api.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to examine how a Geolocation field created via the UI appears in the metadata api. Doesn't it split into separate fields? Like `myField__Latitude__s` and `myField__Longitude__s`?

Comment: The Spring 14 release notes mention a beta that exposes a read only Geolocation compound field in the SOAP and REST APIs. So now you have one geolocation field that gets tree separate fields in the API>

Comment: @DanielBallinger  Thanks for reply. Today I checked my metadata api version and it is 29.0 . Is it the reason i am not getting geolocation type not even Latitude/Longitude.

Comment: I can get geolocation field via myField__Latitude__s and myField__Longitude__s, but how can i create this type of field in my java program because there is no such type of FieldType.location or FieldType.geolocation ?

Comment: The beta read only Geolocation would be in API v30.0 for Spring 14. It would be a bit surprising if it really wasn't possible to create a Geolocation field in the Metadata API. Otherwise how would people migrate or package such a field?

Comment: Can you access the [Field Type](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/field_types.htm) `location`?

Comment: I can access the location field but using com.sforce.soap.enterprise package(com.sforce.soap.enterprise. FieldType) and I am looking in com.sforce.soap.metadata package(because I am using metadata package to create custom fields)

Comment: com.sforce.soap.enterprise package allow me to set FieldType.location  but  metadata api  doesn't provide me this.